# Cocoa App hangs when using NSTextView with NSScrollView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appkit, nstextview, nsscrollview

I am reading some file content and trying to display on NSTextView with NSScrollView.
My app hangs when I try to display the content of a very large file. The actual scenario is:

- open the file.
- Read its content in NSData and convert it to NSString.
- Create a NSScrollView.
- Create a NSTextView.
- Set the above created NSString to NSTextView.

File Size is extremely large . It contains around 106010441 lines.

My app is successfully able to show the inital content of the file, until I scroll down it starts hanging and become very slow.
If I click on text area and press command + a to select all and start scrolling, it completely freezes.

I dont know , what I am doing wrong.

Here is my ViewController.m content:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    /
    NSString * path = Path_to_file;
    NSFileHandle * fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];
    NSData * buffer = [fileHandle readDataToEndOfFile];
    raw_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[buffer bytes] length:[buffer length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}


- (void)setRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject {
    [super setRepresentedObject:representedObject];
}


- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    _Scroller.hasVerticalScroller = YES;
    _Scroller.hasHorizontalScroller = YES;
    _Scroller.autoresizingMask = NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable;

    NSSize contentSize = _Scroller.contentSize;


    NSTextView* _textView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0,
                                                                         contentSize.width, contentSize.height)];

    _textView.minSize = NSMakeSize(0.0, contentSize.height);
    _textView.maxSize = NSMakeSize(FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX);
    _textView.verticallyResizable = YES;
    _textView.horizontallyResizable = YES;
    _textView.autoresizingMask = NSViewWidthSizable;
    _textView.textContainer.containerSize = NSMakeSize(contentSize.width, FLT_MAX);
    _textView.textContainer.widthTracksTextView = YES;
    _textView.automaticSpellingCorrectionEnabled = NO;
    _textView.continuousSpellCheckingEnabled = NO;

    _Scroller.documentView = _textView;
    _textView.string = raw_string;
}
@end
```

Comment: It's a bit old at this point but maybe have a look at how things are setup in the TextEdit sample code: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/TextEdit/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011741

Comment: Add a clip view between the scroll view and the text view. Create an Xcode project, add a text view in Interface Builder and examine the view hierarchy and the auto resizing masks.

Comment: Is it working with a small text file?

Comment: @Willeke yes, it is working with smaller size text files

Comment: Can you open the big text file in TextEdit?

Comment: @Willeke Yes textEdit is able to open the file.

Comment: readDataToEndOfFile:
"Synchronously reads the available data up to the end of file or maximum number of bytes" why don't you read data in chunks by using "readDataOfLength:" isn't it @Willeke